# Why is the sum of elements in each row of $X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T$ in OLS equal to $1$?

Tags: linear-regression, projection-matrices

I have noticed that the sum of elements in each row (and each column, since the matrix is symmetric) of $X(X^T X)^{-1}X^T$, where $X$ is the information matrix in the OLS regression, is equal to 1. Is there a proof for this result, and what is the intuitive explanation?

Comment: What properties does $X$ have?

Comment: @amd Thank you reading and replying to my question. X has a first column containing only 1s, like used in OLS regression. Otherwise, it is just some random numbers. I don't think it is anything more specific than that.

Comment: You also know that $X$ has linearly-independent columns, otherwise $X^TX$ is singular. The key, I believe, is going to be that column of 1s.

Comment: Yes, absence of colinearity is one of the requirements in OLS. Yes, the 1s indeed look to be crucial. I thought that this is a well known property of this "projection" in OLS, but couldn't find any discussion of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The column of $1$s in $X$ is the key. The matrix $P=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ computes orthogonal projection onto the columns of $X$. This map is the identity on the column space of $X$, so in particular every column of $X$ is an eigenvector of $P$ with eigenvalue $1$. Right-multiplying a matrix by $\mathbb 1 = (1,\dots,1)^T$ sums its rows, and since we have $P\mathbb 1=\mathbb 1$ this means that all of the row sums are equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to digest that. Another point: given that the rows all sum to 1, it suggests that the entries are distributed as some kind of Dirichlet distribution, although not on (0,1) as negative elements also occur. I wonder if they are restricted however to lie in (-1,1)?

Comment: @Confounded Think about the images of the standard basis vectors under this projection and what it does to norms of vectors.